# Parsing a xml file value is coming null

Tags: android, xml

i am parsing a xml file and i am able to get the certain values but for some element i.e li is not returning the value,please have a look on these file

xml:

```
<DRM>
   <pages>
       <page id= 1>
         <print> 
            <wholepage >N </wholepage>
            <li>
                   <id>p001_001</id>
                  <id>p002_003</id>
            </li>
        </print>
     <copy>
          <wholepage >N </wholepage>
          <li>
              <id>p001_002</id>
             <id>p002_003<id>
         </li>
      </copy>
    </pages>
<page id = 2>
<print>
<wholepage>Y</wholepage>
</print>
<copy>
<wholepage>Y</wholepage>
</copy>
</page>
</page>
</pages>
</DRM>
```

parser :

```
 XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
         String data=c1.decrypt(baseurl+"/Metadata/Metadata1.xml");
         System.out.println(data);

             Document doc = parser.getDomElement(data); 
     NodeList n=doc.getElementsByTagName("pages");

     Element e = (Element) n.item(0);

     NodeList nl_li_l2=e.getElementsByTagName("page");

            for(int i=0;i<nl_li_l2.getLength();i++)
            {

                Element e_1 = (Element) nl_li_l2.item(i);
                String val=         e_1.getAttribute("id");
                System.out.println("val:"+val);

                NodeList print_list=e_1.getElementsByTagName("print");
                for(int j=0;j<print_list.getLength();j++)
                {
                Element e_2 = (Element)print_list.item(j);
                String wp=   parser.getValue(e_2,"wholepage");
                System.out.println("p whole page:"+wp);

                NodeList print_li=e_2.getElementsByTagName("li");

                for(int h=0;h<print_li.getLength();h++)
                {                   
                    Element e_4 = (Element)print_li.item(h);

                    NodeList print_i=e_4.getElementsByTagName("id");

                    for(int h1=0;h1<print_i.getLength();h1++)
                    {
                    Element e_5 = (Element)print_i.item(h1);
                    String wp1=  parser.getValue(e_5,"id");
                    System.out.println("wp1"+wp1);
                    }

                }
                }               
                NodeList copy_list=e_1.getElementsByTagName("copy");
                for(int j=0;j<copy_list.getLength();j++)
                {
                Element e_5 = (Element) copy_list.item(j);
                String cp=   parser.getValue(e_5,"wholepage");
                System.out.println(" c whole page:"+cp);

                NodeList copy_li=e_5.getElementsByTagName("li");

                for(int h=0;h<copy_li.getLength();h++)
                {
                    Element e_6 = (Element)copy_li.item(h);
                    NodeList copy_id=e_6.getElementsByTagName("id");
                    for(int h1=0;h1<copy_id.getLength();h1++)
                    {
                    Element e_id = (Element)copy_id.item(h1);               
                    String cc=   parser.getValue(e_id,"id");
                    System.out.println("cp1"+cc);
                    }
                }

                }
            }
```

but here i am not able to get the value inside li tag in xml.Loop is running perfectly but value is null,please help me to find out where the exact problem is?

Comment: Format your sentences properly before submitting a question .

Comment: Have you actually run the code on the XML? Because your XML is not-well-formed (attribute values must be quoted) and would throw an exception.

Comment: but xml given to me is in the same form ,please tell me while the value of li tag is not coming ,here i am able to get all the values except li tag that is empty or null

Comment: I think the problem is with `N ` , as it contains one extra Space.

Comment: @Lucifer but those values i am able to get only thing is the values mentioned inside li tag i.e id ,those values are not coming

Comment: @Daniel that is because, after `N` there is a white space, and so for next element LI it is taking that white space. However I am not 100% sure about this.

Comment: @Lucifer i'll try after removing space and update you

Comment: @Lucifer thats not the problem even after removing space also not getting the values of id inside li tag

Comment: @Daniel ok than, something else is the reason for problem.

Comment: can anyone please give me the solution??